# Privileges for database owner; application user

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Quick version:

What command should I issue to enable a database owner to allow it to access tables in this database and can this be done from that owner's account?

---

Longer Version:

I am creating a database on RDS.  I have a 'root' user that I have configured with Amazon.

Amazon automatically creates the group role 'rds_superuser' which is very privileged, but not actually a superuser.

I am creating a database and user for the application as follows:

```
create database master_integration;
CREATE ROLE master_application LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '...' VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE master_integration TO GROUP rds_superuser WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE master_integration TO GROUP master_application;

\c master_integration;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER ON TABLES TO rds_superuser;
```

*I updated this script to reflect suggestions by Craig Ringer regarding how I should be handling this.*

When the app connects (with the master_application credentials) it creates  (and therefore owns) the tables.

My issue is that I cannot use my administrative (rootish) log in to run queries because that user has no privileges on the table.

I have been able to solve this before by running the following from the application account:

```
GRANT ALL privileges ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to rds_superuser;
```

But it seems hacky to have a subordinate user grant privs back to an administrative user.

So...Is there a command that I can run before or after I create the tables from the application which will ensure that the owner of the database can access the tables within the database?

---

*update after re-trying the alter default privilegs...*

This still does not grant access to the tables; I see it being suggested elsewhere and it makes complete sense, but it is not working for me.  From a psql shell:

```
master_integration=> \ddp
                           Default access privileges
      Owner       | Schema | Type  |             Access privileges             
------------------+--------+-------+-------------------------------------------
 integration_root |        | table | integration_root=arwdDxt/integration_root+
                  |        |       | rds_superuser=arwdDxt/integration_root
(1 row)

master_integration=> \dp users
                           Access privileges
 Schema | Name  | Type  | Access privileges | Column access privileges 
--------+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------------------
 public | users | table |                   | 
(1 row)
```

integration_root is my superuser-ish user and users is a table within my database.

---

Update

I got a fairly useless response from someone at Amazon.

They asked me to call ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES from the master_application login.  While this would probably work, it would not answer my question (which is how do I make this happen solely from the rds_superuser account).

I asked them to clarify this and they went away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html).

Give the `rds_superuser` default access rights to all new tables.

This only affects tables created after the `ALTER`. For existing tables you must `GRANT` rights.

Comment: I had tried to do this.  I worded this poorly in the original question, I have edited it to show exactly the command that I was executing.  Did I get something wrong?

Comment: It only affects tables created *after* the `ALTER`. When'd you do it? For existing tables you must `GRANT` rights.

Comment: I altered the default privs, then created the tables.  I am going to try it again, perhaps I made a mistake.

Comment: Still no luck with this, although it absolutely seems like the command that should solve the problem.  I updated the command to include the output from \ddp and \dp from one of the tables.

Comment: Awfully odd. Can you reproduce the problem in a regular (non-RDS) PostgreSQL?

Comment: I can not reproduce this with a local server, so it seems to be something peculiar with the RDS postgres.  I'll keep looking to see if I can spot the difference.

Comment: @AndyDavis This might also be a good time to get Amazon's support team into the picture; there could well be a bug here. I recommend creating a self-contained test case that can be reproduced on a fresh RDS instance first, though.

Comment: I am going to go ahead and accept this as the answer because I think this is an RDS anomaly.  This is the correct way to solve the problem.  If I get any further information from the Amazon folks, I will update.

Comment: @AndyDavis - I've seen that you've meanwhile [asked in the RDS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=537801&#537801) and got a late response from AWS, oddly stating that they _have sent you a PM to further discuss your situation_ (similar to a few other related posts there in fact). I wonder why they might be secretive about this - have you received a satisfying result at least? I'd like to avoid asking basically the same question, only to wait for more than a week for nothing eventually ;)

Comment: @SteffenOpel I have no idea why they didn't respond to my question in the public formum.  I did edit my question to summarize the interaction, which was, unfortunately, pretty useless.

Comment: @AndyDavis - that's a pity; thanks for sparing me that round trip at this point, highly appreciated! Let's hope they'll lift some restrictions over time, a few responses suggest they are considering this at least (which would be in line with the demand driven product evolution seen elsewhere from AWS), even though I suspect security considerations behind the limitations at hand, which might be harder to address properly.

Answer (score 0):

The public schema is supposed to be visible by all users. You should not restrict rights of public schema to just one group.

So, if you do not use:

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO GROUP rds_superuser WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

You may safely work with the public schema with all accounts.

If you do not want specific accounts to mess up your public schema tables, then create a new role (for users of your app) and revoke rights from this particular role inside the public schema. Something like:

```
CREATE USER mywebuser WITH PASSWORD '*****';
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public FROM mywebuser;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO mywebuser; (or whatever rights you need to provide)
```

Not the other way around as you try to do it.

Comment: Huh? A `GRANT` should never be able to *reduce* access rights. I'm not convinced. Note that rights on a schema don't get inherited by new tables in that schema, either, so having access to the `public` schema doesn't mean you can use tables within it.

Comment: I did finally get to try this out and it does not help the situation.

Comment: I have edited the question to eliminate the Grant that @Aleandros was referring to.  It didn't seem to be the problem, but I think it was a distraction.